# Projective dimension over noetherian rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ a commutative Noetherian ring and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module such that $\operatorname{pd}_R(M)=d < \infty$, where $\operatorname{pd}_R(M)$ denotes the projective dimension of $M$.

Can I prove that there exists a projective resolution of $M$
$0 \to P_d \to P_{d-1} \to \cdots \to P_1 \to P_0 \to M \to 0$ where each $P_i$ is finitely generated?

Comment: If the ring is local then it's true. In general, I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; this follows from two key facts:

**Fact 1** If $R$ is Noetherian and $M$ is finitely generated then $M$ has a projective resolution consisting of finitely generated modules.

*Proof Idea.* Construct a free resolution in the standard way, and use the fact that $R$ is Noetherian to verify that the kernels are finitely generated at each step.

**Fact 2** If $M$ has projective dimension $d < \infty$, then for any projective resolution
$$\dots \to F_d \xrightarrow{f_d} \dots \to F_0 \xrightarrow{f_0} M \to 0,$$
$\ker f_d$ is projective.

*Proof Idea.* Use the generalized version of Schanuel's lemma with the assumed projective resolution of length $d$ and the given projective resolution.

---

A complete proof of these facts can be found in [https://www.math.purdue.edu/~iswanso/homologicalalgebra.pdf](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Eiswanso/homologicalalgebra.pdf) (Theorem 6.5 and Proposition 6.6).